# VB StackedArea chart shows 0-points

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

I am creating a `StackedArea` chart in VB.NET and I have some data rows which contain all 0 but one value which is for example 10.

When I draw these values, I loop over all these values, draw a zero and then continue with the next point. An example data row looks like this:

```
"january",0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.03,0.10,0.00,0.00,0.67,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
```

As one can see in the in the **blue** line, there is still something (let's say 1px) displayed, even if the values are all 0.

[image: Example Graph]

My code to draw these series looks the following:

```
Chart.Series.Add(item(1))
For i = 2 To 25
    Dim cell = worksheet.Cells(item(7), i)
    Chart.Series(k - 1).Points.Add(cell.Value)
Next
Chart.Series(k - 1).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedArea
Chart.Series(k - 1).BorderWidth = 0
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Thanks in advance.